# Msbuild exec and curl: Quoting nightmare

Tags: curl, msbuild, cmd

the following msbuild Exec statement

```
<Exec Command="curl.exe -f -O --url &quot;$(SourceURL)&quot;">
```

fails if *SourceURL* contains spaces. Even if I try

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SourceURL>http://www.example.com/url%20with%20spaces</SourceURL>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or even

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SourceURL>http://www.example.com/url&37;20with&37;20spaces</SourceURL>
</PropertyGroup>
```

msbuild automagically translates any of this to spaces (can you believe that?) and curl tries to fetch `http://www.example.com/url`, which yields a 404 error.

I do not understand why. Did I not properly quote the URL argument?

[**update**] On a command prompt, the following works:

```
curl.exe -f -O --url "http://www.example.com/url%20with%20spaces"
```

while this doesn't:

```
curl.exe -f -O --url "http://www.example.com/url with spaces"
```

So my question really boils down to: how do I prevent msbuild from replacing `%20` with whitespace?

cheers
Hendrik

(Using `curl 7.21.7 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5` and msbuild 3.5.30729.1 on Windows 7)

Comment: Have you tried running curl from a command prompt? If so, what exactly do you enter into the command prompt to get it to run successfully?

Comment: Yes, command prompt works. I'll edit the above post to show the command line.

Comment: I've found a solution, but stackoverflow won't let me post it within the next 6 hours... check back later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is:

1. Msbuild replaces `%20` with whitespace
2. Even if you escape the percent sign using either `%2520` or `&37;20`, cmd.exe will replace `%2` with an empty string, such that a 0 remains on the command line.

So the solution is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SourceURL>http://www.example.com/url%25%2520with%25%2520spaces</SourceURL>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Aaaargh. Anyone who doesn't get a headache from such an elaborate escape sequence?

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `&` sign as well:

```
<SourceURL>http://www.example.com/url%2520with%2520spaces</SourceURL>
```

Comment: Still not working -- since the URL is passed to the Exec Task, cmd.exe will eat the "%2" and convert it to an empty string, so I'm left with "". The solution is to add another percent sign: %25%2520 works.